# Moles and SharePoint Behaviour types

Tags: unit-testing, sharepoint, moles, pex-and-moles

We are having problems with the following code:

```
        BSPSite site = new BSPSite();
        BSPWeb web = site.SetRootWeb();
```

The error is :
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Moles, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0ae41878053f6703' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

We have tried rebuilding the Behavoir assembly in the source code to .NET 4 but that didn't go through. We are using v0.94.

Any help would be appreciates.

Comment: No version of SharePoint supports .Net 4.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

2 ) Find Microsoft.Moles.VsHost.x86.exe.config

3) Open and alter by adding next lines under runtime

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
           <dependentAssembly>
                     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Moles" publicKeyToken="0ae41878053f6703" culture="neutral"/>
                     <bindingRedirect oldVersion= "4.0.0.0"
                                              newVersion= "2.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>

     </assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete all the .moles related files and the .moles references.

Then add the Moles reference for each of the assemblies (right click on the original assembly under References and select Add Moles Reference). This will make the .dlls regenerate for the new Moles version.