# Why Moles picks up SharePoint.Behaviors for .NET v4.0 when all the rest is v3.5?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, moles, pex, pex-and-moles

I have a ClassLibrary accessing SharePoint 2010 object model as part of a bigger SP 2010 Sandbox solution. All projects target .NET v3.5 (*not* client profile). Then there's a ASP.NET WebApplication project used to test the ClassLibrary - still .NET v3.5.

I'm trying to use Microsoft Moles in order to mock SPContext.Current - which I already know and have used - and I run into this problem: upon each build, the moles framework will always pick the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Behaviors` DLL for runtime v4.0.30319 in order to copy it into MolesAssemblies. Instead for `Microsoft.SharePoint.Moles` it picks v2.0.50727.

*Incidentally* those are just the DLLs found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\MolesAssemblies\Microsoft.SharePoint\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c`. But I remember during Moles install that both v4.0 and v3.5 moles were created.

Is there a way to *tell* Moles to build and/or copy the DLL for runtime v3.5?
Or is there a special place were I should build and store them, in order to let Moles pick them up?

Somehow I also had a look at the temporary options file created during build (`...\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args`) and the last options are actually `/clrversion:v2.0.50727 /clrversion2 /targetframeworkversion:v3.5`.

Environment: Windows 7 64bit, VS 2010 SP1, Moles v0.94.51023.0 - .NET v4.0.30319 (Moles only install, no Pex).

Comment: This question I think it's related, but it has no answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282431/moles-references-a-net-4-assembly-in-a-net-3-5-project . Probably this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975474/moles-and-sharepoint-behaviour-types

Comment: I do not have (yet) an answer to this. But in order to make it work, I had to compile SharePoint 2010 behaviors for .NET 3.5 from Moles sources. Then: I removed the original .moles file and moled DLL references; I added the compiled SP behaviors DLL as any other reference from file system.

Comment: I withdrew my answer, because I simply don't know the answer to your question.  I am going to research this.  I'd rather not pollute the thread and add confusion.